# How can we compute bounding box of object in threejs

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

```
function loadModel(){
    switchCamera("orthographic");
    var modelLoader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
    modelLoader.load("models/sphere.json", callBack);
```

}

```
function callBack(object3D_geometry){ 
    var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color:0x000000 } );
    var model = new THREE.Mesh( object3D_geometry, material);
    scene.add(model);

    console.log(object3D_geometry);
    //console.log(object3D_geometry.boundingBox); 
    //model.geometry.computeBoundingBox;
    modelBoundingBox = model.geometry.boundingBox;

    console.log("model Bounding box");
    console.log(modelBoundingBox);

    renderer.render( scene, camera );
```

}

I am trying to calculate bounding box of 3d json models. Right now I'm just using a sphere. When I try to get bounding box it says null. How can i get bounding box so that even if I load complex model it will calculate bounding box of whole model.

Comment: `geometry.computeBoundingBox` is a declaration. To execute a method you need the parenthesis > `geometry.computeBoundingBox()`

Comment: I tried with parenthesis but it still says undefined.

Comment: How do we load object at origin. I tried setting geometry and mesh x,y,z position to 0. but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I wrote this method to get maximum and minimum values. I will try to work with this for now. However **I would appreciate if anybody would answer why boundingBox is not working.**

```
function calculate_XYZ_Max_Min(modelVertices){
    var min_X = modelVertices[0].x;
    var max_X = modelVertices[0].x;
    var min_Y = modelVertices[0].y;
    var max_Y = modelVertices[0].y;
    var min_Z = modelVertices[0].z;
    var max_Z = modelVertices[0].z;


    for (var i=1; i< modelVertices.length; i++){

        if (modelVertices[i].x > max_X)     max_X = modelVertices[i].x;
        if (modelVertices[i].x < min_X)     min_X = modelVertices[i].x;
        if (modelVertices[i].y > max_Y)     max_Y = modelVertices[i].y;
        if (modelVertices[i].y < min_Y)     min_Y = modelVertices[i].y;
        if (modelVertices[i].z > max_Z)     max_Z = modelVertices[i].z;
        if (modelVertices[i].z < min_Z)     min_Z = modelVertices[i].z;
    }

    return{
        xMin: Math.floor(min_X);
        xMax: Math.ceil(max_X); 
        yMin: Math.floor(min_Y);
        yMax: Math.ceil(max_Y);
        zMin: Math.floor(min_Z);
        zMax: Math.ceil(max_Z);
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI the code you posted doesnt work. Do you spot the error?  `if (modelVertices[i].x > max_Y)     max_Y = modelVertices[i].y;`

Comment: Oh yes I see. Thank You.